# Unexpected borders on legends of stacked bars in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I would like to visualize numbers of female and male passengers on the Titanic traveling in 1st, 2nd, and 3rd class using stacked bars in pgfplots.

The code here:

```tex
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\definecolor{acolor}{HTML}{D55E00}
\definecolor{bcolor}{HTML}{0072B2}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
    bar width=2cm,
    axis lines=left,
    axis line style={opacity=0},
    ytick=\empty,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ymin=0, ymax=750,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    nodes near coords,
    symbolic x coords={1st class, 2nd class, 3rd class},
    xtick=data,
    legend style={draw=none, at={(0.5,-0.1)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},]
    \addplot+[ybar, fill=acolor, draw=none, text=white] plot coordinates {(1st class, 179)(2nd class, 172)(3rd class, 499)};
    \addplot+[ybar, fill=bcolor, draw=none, text=white] plot coordinates {(1st class, 143)(2nd class, 107)(3rd class, 212)};
    \legend{male passengers,female passengers}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

But, the borders on legends are displayed incorrectly. I expect there is no any border in the legend area. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
```

(or the version you have; you are running with the original "bugs" enabled otherwise...)

and then add the option

```
legend image post style={fill, draw=white},
```

after the `legend style`. I though that `draw=none` should have worked, but it seems that it's ignored. (I discovered it looking in "All supported styles" in the manual).

Comment: +1 This must be a bug. The draw option(e.g. `draw=red`) from `addplot` is correctly inherited, but `draw=none` is ignored. (both in `\addplot` and `legend image post style`)

Answer (score 1):

Use `legend image code` to create the legend image you want. (Here a rectangle somewhat below the baseline)

The legends squares were drawn without borders (using `draw=none`)

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{crop,tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\definecolor{acolor}{HTML}{D55E00}
\definecolor{bcolor}{HTML}{0072B2}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
            bar width=2cm,
            axis lines=left,
            axis line style={opacity=0},
            ytick=\empty,
            major x tick style = transparent,
            ymin=0, ymax=750,
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
            nodes near coords,
            symbolic x coords={1st class, 2nd class, 3rd class},
            xtick=data,
        legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[#1, draw=none] (0cm,-0.2cm) rectangle (0.4cm,0.2cm);
        },  
        legend style={
            % no rectangle around
            draw=none, % 
            % position of the legend
            at={(0.05,-0.2)},
            anchor= west,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/column 2/.style={column sep=15pt},
        },
            ]       
            \addplot+[ybar, fill=acolor, draw=none, text=white] plot coordinates {(1st class, 179)(2nd class, 172)(3rd class, 499)};
            \addplot+[ybar, fill=bcolor, draw=none, text=white] plot coordinates {(1st class, 143)(2nd class, 107)(3rd class, 212)};
            \legend{male passengers,female passengers}          
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```